# Image gets distorted sometime while uploading

Tags: android, file-upload, mime, multipart

I am using **MIME multipart** for uploading images to server. Sometime image get distorted. How to resolve this issue?
Note: Distorted means, some pixels are lost.
I am using following code for uploading:

```
File file = new File(filePath[0]);
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("serverurl");

MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
entity.addPart("Content-Type",new StringBody("multipart/form-data;charset=utf-8"));
entity.addPart("Content-Length", new StringBody(String.valueOf(file.length())));
entity.addPart("UploadContentPostD", new FileBody(file));                   
entity.addPart("DocumentName", new StringBody(file.getName()));

httpPost.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,localContext);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new    InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
```

**Distorted image is:**
[image]

Comment: Please explain exactly what you mean by distorted? Bad pixles / aspect ratio changed / pixels corrupted?

Comment: Pixel are lost so image looks like overlapped some portion to other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Apache Commons](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) for upload and here is my upload code which works perfectly every time...

```
public Integer uploadByteArray(String remoteFilename, byte[] bitmapdata){       
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        PostMethod filePost = new PostMethod( URL_PATH);

        Integer ret = null;

        try {           
            Part[] parts = new Part[2];
            parts[0] = new StringPart("file_name" ,remoteFilename);

            ByteArrayPartSource ps = new ByteArrayPartSource("file", bitmapdata);
            parts[1] = new FilePart("file", ps);

            filePost.setRequestEntity(new MultipartRequestEntity(parts,
                    filePost.getParams()));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
        }

        try {
            ret = client.executeMethod(filePost);
            Log.d(TAG, "statusCode>>>" + ret);
            if(ret != 200){
                Log.d(TAG, "Error:" + ret + " from server. Please try again later.");
            }else{
                responseBody = filePost.getResponseBodyAsString();
                Log.d(TAG, filePost.getResponseBodyAsString());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
        }

        filePost.releaseConnection();

        return ret;
    }
```

If you continue to see your problem recurring, I would use MD5 on the file you get on the server and send that value back in the response and compare it to a local MD5 of the file you've sent up. If they're not the same, you know something went wrong.

Comment: I am also using same Apache library with my code...but sometimes it breaks, please see the attached image

Comment: like I said, you'll want to do an MD5 of the received file and re-upload if the file isn't identical to the version on the source client.