# StringBody doesnt get the full string

Tags: java, android, apache, entity, http-post

I don't understand: In android, I dont get the full string returned I entered into the stringbody. I have checked that the string is fully saved but when it passes to the stringbody it just breaks. In a desktop version of the same application, the results are sucessful. But in Android, a random part in the end of the string is lost. If i try to save the resulted string after it is lost, the string saves in the same spot. I dont use any accents or special chars.
Example that from a test:

First write:

> This is a test bio with a random message that i'm writting on the go.
>   If this gets cut like i am expecting something is going to be left
>   out. Lets see what is going to happen.

One save saves this:

> This is a test bio with a random message that i'm writting on the go.
>   If this gets cut like i am expecting something is going to be left out

Second save:

> This is a test bio with a random message that i'm writting on the go.
>   If this gets cut like i am

The code is

```
protected void gravarPerfil() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
    StringBody sAcerca = null, sLoc = null;

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    if (cookie != null) {
        client.getCookieStore().addCookie(cookie);
    }

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(address + "/dinamicas/editarPerfil");

    FileBody imagebin = null;

    if (imgfile != null) {
        imagebin = new FileBody(imgfile);
    }

    Log.v("msg", acerca.getText().toString());
```

Here is the part where my filebody doesnt load the whole string

```
    sAcerca = new StringBody(acerca.getText().toString());
    sLoc = new StringBody(local.getText().toString());


    try {

        entity.addPart("acerca", sAcerca);
        entity.addPart("localizacao", sLoc);
        if (imgfile != null) {
            entity.addPart("foto", imagebin);
        }

        post.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I've had a simular issue before. I completely un-installed the app from the emulator/device and tried again - Then it was fine.  Once-in a-blue-moon, Things gets corrupted and the app wipe fixes it.

Comment: uninstalled, reinstalled, created new emulator, removed the jars from apache and installed new ones of the same version... Nothing works. :\

Comment: It still could be your server (between Android and the server) so [I think this may be what you need](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505811/image-gets-distorted-sometime-while-uploading) - Similar to your issue but with images while sending multiPart data.

Comment: Tried that, the error still persists... Oh well, maybe is something to do with the char codification, I don't know... For a walk around I discovered that the end that is removed is always between 5 - 13 chars... So I am adding 15 # to the end of the string, being then removed in the server side. It's not pretty, but it works. 

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't got any reasonable solution, so I applied a walk around. I discovered that the end that is removed is always between 5 - 13 chars... So I am adding 15 # to the end of the string, being then removed in the server side. It's not pretty, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the final log line is giving you something weird?:

```
 Log.v("msg", response.toString());
```

because it will.

Try this:

```
InputStream responseStream = response..getEntity().getContent();
String textResponse = StreamConverter.convertStreamToString(responseStream);
Log.v("msg", "Received:"+ textResponse);


public class StreamConverter {

    public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            Writer writer = new StringWriter();

            char[] buffer = new char[1024];
            try {
                Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"),1024);
                int n;
                while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
                }
            } finally {
                inputStream.close();
            }
            return writer.toString();
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My problem is with the saving string to the filebody. The string when passes to the filebody looses some data. The server that is running in eclipse too works good and has no error. The message I get in the server is the cut version.